# Calculating total width within elements using jQuery using each

Tags: jquery, each

I am trying to calculate the total width of all divs within a section. I would like to calculate the width of each div within  .mainScroll, add them up, and set the width of the section to that os the sum of its contents. Here is my HTML markup.

```
    <section>
        <div class="mainScroll">
             <div>some content</div>
             <div>some content</div>
             <div>some content</div>
        </div>
    </section>
    <section>
        <div class="mainScroll">
             <div>some content</div>
             <div>some content</div>
             <div>some content</div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

And here is my jQuery thus far:

```
var totalWidth = 0;

$('section').each(function(){
    var select = $(this).find('.mainScroll div');
    select.each(function(index) {
        totalWidth += parseInt($(this).outerWidth(true), 10);   
    });

    $(this).css({ 'width' : totalWidth});
    var totalWidth = 0;

});
```

This outputs NaN.  How can I set this up so it loops through each section, then loops through that sections individual elements, adds up its height, and then sets the section to have that exact height?

Comment: For starters... I'm assuming `var select = $(this).find('.mainScrolld div');` should be `var select = $(this).find('.mainScroll div');`? You have an extra 'd' there. ;)

Comment: yes that was a typo, fixed now

Comment: I recommend inserting `console.log` statements in your for loop. My guess would be that some of your numbers are being typed as strings, and `"2" + 3 = NaN`

Comment: I used console.log. WHen I remove var totalWidth = 0; it does not output Nan\. It outputs the correct numbers, but it adds the first log to the second. The var totalWidth = 0; is simply trying to reset the totalWidth for the second iteration.

Comment: Oh, also your use of the `totalWidth` variable is not good. Move the first `var totalWidth = 0;` to be the first line inside the `each()` function, and remove the second copy of that line you currently have as the line of the `each()`.

Comment: Thanks @Nate. That makes sense. How would you recommend creating a new variable that adds the total width of all sections combined as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

look this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/c6LSN/2/)

```
$('section').each(function(){
    var totalWidth = 0;
    var select = $(this).find('.mainScroll div');
    select.each(function(index) {
        totalWidth = +(totalWidth)+(+$(this).outerWidth(true));   
    });

    //$(this).css({ 'width' : totalWidth});
    alert(+(totalWidth)); //  total
    var totalWidth = 0;
});
```